# Graphs that are non-Eulerian but are Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

I understand the conditions necessary for a graph to have Eulerian and Hamiltonian paths.
I could find examples for graphs that are Eulerian but not Hamiltonian. 
Can someone give me graphs that are non-Eulerian but are Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 2):

Make a cycle on $4$ or more vertices.  Then join two unjoined vertices with an edge. Then join two different unjoined vertices with an edge.

Answer (score 1):

A $K_4$ is Halmiltonian but not Eulerian. You can't traverse every edge in this graph in a walk without repeating edges.